# Python regex function to arrange key:value in descending order. Wherein the key is alphanumeric and the value is digits

Tags: python, regex, pandas, sorting

Say I have a column which has values like:

```
**Input**

A12:67, A18:24, B11:89
A12:78, A19:100
B12:100, A20:19, A01:91
```

I would like the piece of code that I am working on to return:

```
**Expected Output**

B11:89, A12:67, A18:24
A19:100, A12:78
B12:100, A01:91, A20:19
```

I'm trying to get the code to sort this key-value pair based on the value of the item in descending order
This is the code I have written as of now, but it's sorting based on the digits in the Key and not the value.

```
def sortitem(df):
    sorteddf = df.apply(lambda x :",".join(sorted(x.split(", "), key=lambda y: int(re.search(r"(\d+)", y).group(1)), reverse=True)))
    return sorteddf
```

The code outputs:

```
**Output received**

A18:24, A12:67, B11:89
A19:100, A12:78
A20:19, B12:100, A01:91
```

Which is not the expected output. Please help with the corrections in the code required to achieve the desired output.
Thank you.

Comment: I don't do dataframes, but given a list `x = ["A12:67", "A18:24", "B11:89"]` you can sort it the way you want by doing: `sorted(x, key=lambda x: x.split(':')[-1], reverse=True)` which will give you: `['B11:89', 'A12:67', 'A18:24']`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
df['Input'].apply(lambda r: ', '.join(sorted(r.split(', '), key=lambda s: int(s.split(':')[-1]), reverse=True)))
```

Pandas test:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Input':['A12:67, A18:24, B11:89','A12:78, A19:100','B12:100, A20:19, A01:91']})
df['Input'] = df['Input'].apply(lambda r: ', '.join(sorted(r.split(', '), key=lambda s: int(s.split(':')[-1]), reverse=True)))
>>> df
                     Input
0   B11:89, A12:67, A18:24
1          A19:100, A12:78
2  B12:100, A01:91, A20:19
```

NOTES:

- `r.split(', ')` - splits each cell value with comma+space
- `sorted(..., key=lambda s: int(s.split(':')[-1]), reverse=True)` - sorts the split chunks by the integer value that is after `:` (obtained by splitting the cell value with `:` and last item accessed with `[-1]` and then cast to `int` using `int(s.split(':')[-1])`) in descending order (due to `reverse=True`
- `', '.join(...)` - combines back the split chunks

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Input': [
        ['A12:67', 'A18:24', 'B11:89'],
        ['A12:78', 'A19:100'],
        ['B12:100', 'A20:19', 'A01:91']]
})

df['Results'] = df.Input.apply(
    lambda lst: sorted(lst, key=lambda s: int(s.split(':')[1]), reverse=True))

print(df)

                       Input                    Results
0   [A12:67, A18:24, B11:89]   [B11:89, A12:67, A18:24]
1          [A12:78, A19:100]          [A19:100, A12:78]
2  [B12:100, A20:19, A01:91]  [B12:100, A01:91, A20:19]
```

It is not clear from your code whether your data is already formatted as lists of strings (like `['A12:67', 'A18:24', 'B11:89']`) or just strings that have comma+space seperated values (like `'A12:67, A18:24, B11:89'`). If the latter is the case, you can do

```
df.Input = df.Input.str.split(', ')
```

before applying the previous function.

Comment: The output here isn't what I am looking for. This code here is alphabetically arranging the keys irrespective of the values.